# Angular 2 CLI ng build --prod causes unpredictable 404's when on a production server

Tags: angular, angular-cli

With Angular CLI, I've tried running the command `ng build -prod --base-href /dist` just to test out the prod version of my app on a personal website of mine. However, when I upload the directory with the files, I just get a bunch of 404's and unpredictable issues. When I go to `http://<the-url>/dist`, I get this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://<url-omitted>/main.a700d1a79f497ebd40b5.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://<url-omitted>/inline.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://<url-omitted>/scripts.bd14ddfbf2a53470a559.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://<url-omitted>/inline.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://<url-omitted>/styles.80fef94eb489169fb077.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://<url-omitted>/scripts.bd14ddfbf2a53470a559.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://<url-omitted>/main.a700d1a79f497ebd40b5.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

It's pretty crucial that I get this sorted out in the next couple of days, so has anyone ran into this issue and had any luck on solving it?

I should note I'm also using angular cli version `1.0.0-beta.16`

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?